# Proxy config for cross site Ajax (JSON) calls in Websphere Portal 7

Tags: ajax, json, websphere-portal

First off, I'm new to portal development in general, and thus have no previously experience with Websphere Portal.  Note: URLs have been changed to protect the innocent.

I have a portlet on Websphere Portal 7 where I'm trying to make an Ajax call (a POST in this case) to another server.  I know I have to create the proxy-config and wire up the ProxyServlet so Portal will allow the cross site ajax call, and I have done that.  However, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden message when calling the proxied service.

Here's my proxy-config.xml:

```
<proxy:proxy-rules 
      xmlns:proxy="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sw/ajax/proxy-config/1.1" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
      <proxy:mapping contextpath="/proxy" url="*"/> 
      <proxy:policy acf="none" url="*"> 
            <proxy:actions> 
                  <proxy:method>GET</proxy:method> 
                  <proxy:method>POST</proxy:method> 
            </proxy:actions> 
      </proxy:policy> 
      <proxy:policy acf="none" url="https://subdomain.domain.org/ss/services/*"> 
            <proxy:actions> 
                  <proxy:method>GET</proxy:method> 
                  <proxy:method>POST</proxy:method> 
            </proxy:actions> 
      </proxy:policy> 
      <proxy:meta-data> 
            <proxy:name>max-connections-per-host</proxy:name> 
            <proxy:value>5</proxy:value> 
      </proxy:meta-data> 
      <proxy:meta-data> 
            <proxy:name>max-total-connections</proxy:name> 
            <proxy:value>100</proxy:value> 
      </proxy:meta-data> 
</proxy:proxy-rules>
```

Here is the ProxyServlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.wps.proxy.servlet.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ss/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/proxy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is the URL that I'm attempting to call from javascript (via jQuery):

```
"wps/proxy/https/subdomain.domain.org/ss/services/service1"
```

I'm currently getting 403 Forbidden "The URL you tried to access through the proxy is not allowed" error message.  And this is the URL Firebug shows the portlet is hitting (seems to be correct): 
http://portalsubdomain.domain.org:77777/wps/proxy/https/subdomain.domain.org/ss/services/service1.

Based on the proxy docs for wp7, I know 403 means one of the following:

- The request was not accepted by the proxy, that is the proxy found no matching access policy that grants access to the target server.
- Basic authentication failed.

It should've found the proxy policy since I have it defined for all URLs, so what am I missing?  I'm figuring I either haven't configured the proxy policy correctly (authentication?) or I haven't constructed the URL in the JSON call correctly.  I reviewed the format "rules" but haven't been able to come up with a solution that works.

A couple of things to note:

- This portlet is on a child page of another page, and dojo is part of a custom theme we created
- We are using LDAP to log into the portal, so not sure if that makes any difference as well.  I'm logging in with portal admin rights when running this.
- The URL for the page where the portlet is being loaded (and thus the page/space structure) is http://portalsubdomain.domain.org:77777/wps/demoportal/home/demo/ajaxTest.  Not sure what the proxy is looking for, but the proxy-config.xml is located within my portlet's WEB-INF folder.
- If I change the URL in my JSON call to wps/demoportal/home/demo/ajaxTest/proxy/https/subdomain.domain.org/ss/services/service1, I get the HTML for the ajaxTest page in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! I needed to get the context path of the portlet and prepend it to the service URL.

Since my service call is in a separate .js file (via JavascriptMVC & jQuery), my quick and dirty fix is to create a JavaScript variable on the .jsp in order to get the portlet context path like so:

```
var globalRequestContextUrl = "<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()) %>";
```

then in my ajax call, I prepend the context url to my call to the proxy like so:

```
globalRequestContextUrl + "https/subdomain.domain.org/ss/services/service1"
```

Now I'm fighting SSL certificate issues, but I'm definitely getting through the proxy now.